# In memoir, remove all margins from a page?

Tags: header-footer, memoir, titles

I'm trying to implement a title page for a book-like document with memoir.  It has some specific dimension requirements measured from the page edge, for example “place the upper edge of the title text 2.5 inches from the upper page edge”, and “author name 3 inches from the bottom page edge”.

My strategy so far is to remove all kinds of margins from the title page, including left/right margin and top/bottom space, and place a bunch of boxes/glues.  How can I remove all kinds of margins just for the title page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The key here is using the `pass` feature of the `geometry` package that will preserve the underlying page setup of the `memoir` document class, while providing access to `geometry` routines.  Thus, I save the `memoir` page setup initially using a `\savegeometry`.  I then create a `\newgeometry` with no margins and do what needs to be done on that page.  Finally, I restore the original `memoir` geometry that was saved, with a `\loadgeometry`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
\begin{document}
\savegeometry{Mem}
\newgeometry{margin=0pt}
\lipsum[1-10]
\clearpage
\loadgeometry{Mem}
\lipsum[11-20]
\end{document}
```

[image]