# Article class letterhead with logo on first page and different margins on second page

Tags: margins, fancyhdr, minipage, textpos, letterhead

I've been struggling with this for a couple of days. I can't find a good solution for making this letterhead. I want to have the text justified as on the guidelines, but only on the first page: So it starts from the top at 22mm + 45mm = 67mm, but on the second page it starts at 22mm. The solutions I've tried so far did not work: fancyheader, minipage, ifthenelse. Thanks if you have a good idea.

[image: Letterhead]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,top=22mm,left=22mm,bottom=27mm,right=22mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false,
        pdfborder={0 0 0},
        ]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{textblock*}{45mm}[0,0](22mm,27mm)
       \includegraphics[width=45mm]{\logofile}
 \end{textblock*}
\lipsum[1-6]
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `geometry` package allows one to specify page layout, save a page layout, change a page layout, and restore a page layout.  Here is an example that shows how to make the first page different margin size than all the rest: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308795/in-memoir-remove-all-margins-from-a-page

Comment: Thanks, but in this example it is defined what goes on first page and what goes on second page. I want the change to be automatic, otherwise I would have to constantly check where in the letter it goes to page 2 to know where to redefine the margins.

Comment: Never mind. I solved my problem by adding \vspace*. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by adding \vspace*.